# Authorization error when updating a GraphQL object using aws-amplify

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm experiencing issues when using aws amplify to generate a graphql API

My model has mainly two objects (User and messages):

User object:

```
type User
  @model(subscriptions: null)
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "id" }]) {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  username: String!
  avatar: S3Object
  name: String
  conversations: [Conversation] @manyToMany(relationName: "UserConversations")
  messages: [Message!]! @hasMany(indexName: "byAuthor", fields: ["id"])
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
```

Message object:

```
type Message
  @model(subscriptions: null)
  @auth(
    rules: [
      {
        allow: owner
        ownerField: "authorId"
        operations: [create, update, delete]
      }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  author: User @belongsTo(fields: ["authorId"])
  authorId: ID! @index(name: "byAuthor", sortKeyFields: ["content"])
  content: String!
  conversation: Conversation! @belongsTo(fields: ["messageConversationId"])
  messageConversationId: ID!
    @index(name: "byConversation", sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
```

There's a `hasMany`/`belongsTo` relationship between the two and auth rules on both.

After I signin to the API and try to create a user object through the JS API, i'm getting the following error

`'Not Authorized to access messages on type ModelMessageConnection'`

```js
        await AuthAPI.graphql(
          graphqlOperation(createUser, {
            input: {
              id,
              username,
              email,
              name,
            },
          })
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually due to the `message` rule that was missing the `read` action. Changing the object model to the code below fixed it

```
type Message
  @model(subscriptions: null)
  @auth(
    rules: [
      {
        allow: owner
        ownerField: "authorId"
        operations: [create, update, delete, read]
      }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  author: User @belongsTo(fields: ["authorId"])
  authorId: ID! @index(name: "byAuthor", sortKeyFields: ["content"])
  content: String!
  conversation: Conversation! @belongsTo(fields: ["messageConversationId"])
  messageConversationId: ID!
    @index(name: "byConversation", sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
```